# How to get a first and last date in a mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

For the purpose of creating a filter dropdown, I need to find out what the first and last dates are in a mysql table.  I am referring to a field that has a date in it.

My first thought was run a query to pull ALL records, and then do some logic in php to find the first and last date.

Any better suggestions.. my solution seems like it would be very inefficient once there is a huge dataset.

Answer (score 10):

Smallest date:

```
select date_field from table order by date_field asc limit 1;
```

Largest date:

```
select date_field from table order by date_field desc limit 1;
```

Both:

```
select min(date_field),max(date_field) from table;
```

Comment: which of these options is more efficient

Answer (score 5):

Never pull all records! Use SQL for that:

`SELECT your_time_column FROM your_table ORDER BY your_time_column ASC LIMIT  1`

and

`SELECT your_time_column FROM your_table ORDER BY your_time_column DESC LIMIT  1`

or

`SELECT MAX(your_time_column), MIN(your_time_column) FROM your_table`

Comment: which of these options is more efficient

Comment: The one with aggregate functions (MIN(), MAX()) is smaller and you have both values with this query. Just make sure you have indexed your_time_column.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
SELECT MAX(`date`), MIN(`date`)
FROM your_table;
```

Index on a `date` will help.

Answer (score 2):

use **mysql** `min()` and `max()` to select the first and last date

```
select min(date),max(date) from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you order the query by date `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date` in php you can easily get the first and last date:

first: `$first_date = reset($result);`
last: `$last_date = end($result);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make 2 queries (1 for first date, 1 for last date) and union them.

```
(SELECT the_date FROM table ORDER BY the_date ACS  LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT the_date FROM table ORDER BY the_date DESC LIMIT 1)
```